# Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65488 bytes). What to do?

Tags: php, memory

I keep getting fatal errors for the following code. What should I do to get rid of this error? I am trying to make an MVC Framework based site, the problem is with my Models. every thing else works fine.

```
<?php
class Model {
    private $db;
    private $session;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new Database_Model;
        $this->session = new Session_Model;
    }
}

/**
 * Database Class
 */
class Database_Model extends Model {
    public function getUserInfo() {
        return array(
            'Thomas', 'Jane'
        );
    }
}

/**
 * Session Class
 */
class Session_Model extends Model {
    public function getUserId() {
        return $_SESSION['uid'];
    }
}

$b = new Database_Model;
$b->getUserInfo();
?>
```

Comment: Or, increase your memory limit.

Comment: @Brad, there will never be enough memory to run this, it's an infinite recursion.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, Sometimes you need more memory for certain applications.  For instance, when you are processing 8MP images server-side, it tends to take a lot of RAM.  My philosophy is use only what you need.  Without knowing anything about his needs or what he is trying to do, I suggest increasing the memory limit as an alternative when using less memory isn't an option.  It doesn't matter though, as for this question, bfavaretto found the root issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have created an infinite recursion scenario. Look:

- `Database_Model` and `Session_Model` extend `Model`.
- When you instance `Database_Model`, the constructor inherited from `Model` will instance two additional objects on the constructor, `$this->db` and `$this->session`.
- Those new objects also inerit from `Model`, so they will also instance their own  `Database_Model` and `Session_Model`.
- And this goes on infinitely...

Comment: Oh that's a really nice catch

Comment: Is there any way I should use to overcome this and yet work with MVC pattern?

Comment: @OliverMarach One option is to make `Database_Model` and `Session_Model` independent classes, that do not extend  `Model`. Are you building your own framework?

Comment: Its an MVC Framework that uses smarty and also gettext for languages. I want a way the the derived classes can access The properties of my Model class. But it seems that i can figure it out now.